# NullPointerException Trying to create context menu for RecyclerView using Realm

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview, realm

I am trying to create a context menu for a `RecyclerView`, which displays a list of Realm results.

I have already registered for context menu in the `ViewHolder` constructor, implemented `View.OnCreateContextMenuListener` in the ViewHolder class, and implemented it's method. However, i'm getting a `NullPointerException` when trying to retrieve an item from the list when context menu is created:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

    menu.setHeaderTitle(entries.get(info.position).getName());

    menu.add(0,v.getId(),0,"Delete");
    menu.add(0,v.getId(),0,"Cancel");
}
```

Specifically in this line:

```
menu.setHeaderTitle(entries.get(info.position).getName());
```

Keep in mind that "entries" is a list of Realm results of the class "Entry" from my Realm database.

So, apparently I can't access it's position in there. Does anyone know how to deal with this?

This is the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 
'int android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterContextMenuInfo.position' 
on a null object reference
at com.example.developer.appname.adapters.EntryAdapter$ViewHolder.onCreateContextMenu(EntryAdapter.java:101)
```

**EDIT:**

as EpicPandaForce pointed out, the real null object is not the realm object, but the menuInfo. There are a couple of threads about this problem, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884774/null-in-while-using-context-menu-for-recyclerview), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369209/android-recyclerview-item-contextmenu-issue) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36669113/menuinfo-is-null-when-creating-context-menu-on-recycler-view), but none seem to provide a solution as they don't have a "best answer", and I tried many of the answers but none work, at least for me.
Has you guys dealed with this and effectively solved it? If so please help me out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: it says `ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo` is null

Comment: @EpicPandaForce you are right. menuInfo is the null object, apparently there are a couple of threads about this problem here on SO, but all of the solutions are incomplete or don't work